# Facebook Android SDK v2.3 Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult

Tags: android, facebook

<< EDITED >>
I'm trying to upgrade the facebook SDK in my android app. I'm doing it following the docs on the facebook developers site. I want to make to slight modifications

1) I want to make the login from a DialogFragment not directly in the activity
2) I want to do the Facebook login using my own button

This is what my activity look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    private CallbackManager mFBCallbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Setup FB SDK add login callback
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        mFBCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mFBCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FB Login successfull");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "FB Login cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error while performing FB login", e);
            }
        });

        // Open login dialog
        Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new LoginDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // foward onActivityResult call to the FB callback manager
        mFBCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, requestCode, data);
    }
}
```

And this is what my DialogFragment looks like:

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);

        Button fbLoginBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
        fbLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                        getActivity(),
                        Arrays.asList("basic_info"));
            }
        });

        builder.setView(rootView);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I think the setup looks like what the Facebook mentions as required steps however I'm my FacebookCallback.onError(FacebookException) is getting called showing this on the logcat. **Specific message on the exception "Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult"**

```
04-03 12:01:26.390    8229-8229/com.jpdevs.fbv23 D/com.jpdevs.fbv23.MainActivity﹕ Error while performing FB login
    Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:187)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:140)
            at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
            at com.jpdevs.fbv23.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

If you would like to more details I created this repo with the whole project: https://github.com/jorgep19/fb_login

Comment: Is this your complete code...? Please provide complete code and Logcat

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had this problem and you will do a facepalm when i tell you the "secret".
I will explain why this raise, if you just want the solution go to the end.

The source code of facebook throw this error when this happens:

```
if (exception == null && newToken == null && !isCanceled) {
    exception = new FacebookException("Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult");
}
```

So something is happening with this 3 params.

I was reading the code and i see that could be some problem with the resultCode because it's not returning an Activity.RESULT_OK.

**THE KEY**: You have passed the requestCode twice, on the resultCode param too...
Just change this for this:

```
mFBCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, requestCode, data);
```

by

```
mFBCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: I am using it in react native, how can I change it there?

Comment: It was hash issue on my side!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write down the publish_actions instead of basic_info in permission.